# How to retrieve App System Assigned Identity Object Id using Azure Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

I'm using Azure Powershell 3.8.0

I'm trying to fetch the Object ID that can be seen in this screen:

[image: Identity]

I tried using the following:

```
PS> (Get-AzResource -Name  "func-example").Identity.PrincipalId
```

But it does not match the Object ID.

then also:

```
PS> (Get-AzWebApp -Name  "func-example" -ResourceGroupName RGNAME).Identity
```

But also does not match

Does anyone know how to fetch that ID using Azure Powershell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-view-managed-identity-service-principal-powershell),

**With PowerShell :**

```
Get-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName 'func-example'
```

**With CLI :**

```
az ad sp list --display-name 'func-example'
```

Comment: Thank you, it works fantastically `$applicationId = (Get-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName $resourceName).ServicePrincipalNames[0]; Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy –VaultName $SecretsKeyVault -ServicePrincipalName $applicationId -PermissionsToKeys get,list -PermissionsToSecrets get,list -PermissionsToCertificates get,list`